# Capturing video url WKWebView

Tags: swift, swift2, wkwebview

Hi in swift i open a video from WKWebView it automatically opens this video page is there anyway i capture the video link and work with this video's url ?

[image: Video]

Comment: can you get the video url from webview by any way ?

Answer (score -2):

You should implement delegate WKNavigationDelegate and define function decidePolicyForNavigationAction, for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
...

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com")!))
    view.addSubview(webView)
}

func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    let path = navigationAction.request.URL?.absoluteString
    if let path = path {
        if path.rangeOfString("mp4") != nil {
            // This is video link, don't let iOS open video
            decisionHandler(.Cancel)
            print("Process video \(path)")
            return
        }
    }
    // Any other link should be handled by WKWebView
    decisionHandler(.Allow)
}
```

Detect if video link has mp4 in path or some other extension you wish to detect or path, then handle it by yourself.

Comment: Website is using their own video player so if i don't press on fullscreen i can watch on small screen the func you gave me is not working sorry

Comment: It is used when download button click from webview, how to detect the video is playing in player in WKWebView.